# Retrieving re-occurring characters from a string

Tags: vb.net, string

I need to get a certain character from a long string line, that occurs more than once. This is what the string looks like:

```
<Press T><Press Left><Press A><Press C><Press P><Press U><Press G><Press P><Press NumPad7><Press NumPad7><Press A>
```

I need to loop through each set of `<>'s` and get the info that is after each occurrence of the word `Press`. So in this case I would need the info `T, Left, A, C, P, etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this pure `String`-method approach is the most efficient, but it requires the format to be strict:

```
Dim text = "<Press T><Press Left><Press A><Press C><Press P><Press U><Press G><Press P><Press NumPad7><Press NumPad7><Press A>"
Dim allKeys As New List(Of String)
Dim pattern = "Press "
Dim index = text.IndexOf(pattern)
While index >= 0
    index += pattern.Length
    Dim endIndex = text.IndexOf(">", index)
    If endIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim nextKey = text.Substring(index, endIndex - index)
        allKeys.Add(nextKey)
        index = text.IndexOf(pattern, endIndex + 1)
    Else
        Exit While
    End If
End While

Console.Write(String.Join(", ", allKeys))
```

Output: `T, Left, A, C, P, U, G, P, NumPad7, NumPad7, A`

---

Here is the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) that returns all matches, you find the "key" that was pressed in the second group:

```
pattern = "<Press ([^>]+)>"
Dim regex = New Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled And RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For Each match As Match In regex.Matches(text)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1))
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's the same format all the time you can do this in one line. Regex would be better if there's a chance the format would be different (e.g. random number of whitespaces etc..)

```
Dim myString As String = "<Press T><Press Left><Press A><Press C><Press P><Press U><Press G><Press P><Press NumPad7><Press NumPad7><Press A>"
Dim character As String() = myString.Split(New String() {"<Press ", ">"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx, short for regular expressions, is an easy way to parse strings. [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) Provides good information on using RegEx in .NET.  It's how I learned.  The site also provides good info on RegEx in general if you are not familiar.

Edit: RegEx expressions can be complicated to create.  A great tool to help you out with that is [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).  It'll help you create and test very complicated expressions with a minimal of fuss.

Comment: I'd second this advice. For reference, the RegEx for your question is <Press ([^>]+)>.

Comment: Thank you Adrian.  I should have had that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim s As String = "<Press T><Press Left><Press A><Press C><Press P><Press U><Press G><Press P><Press NumPad7><Press NumPad7><Press A>"
    Dim ss() As String = s.Replace("<Press ", "").Split(">"c)
    For i as integer = 0 to ss.count - 2
       Debug.Print(ss(i))
    Next
```

Output:

```
T
Left
A
C
P
U
G
P
NumPad7
NumPad7
A
```

Note that the array ss is one longer than the number of key presses due to the final ">" being treated as another separator by `.split`, you could always remove the final ">"

Comment: Or use `s.Replace("<Press ", "").Split({">"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, anyway, interesting approach.